# Bad review audit question?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just failed this close vote review question https://superuser.com/review/close/390001

I voted to close as opinion based and failed the review.

The core of the question asks "What are the technical pros and cons of using USB flash drives as backup storage? What would be the comparative reliability under safe storage conditions?"

Surely this is either "opinion based" or "too broad"?

Related discussion [What is the definition of "primarily opinion-based" on SU?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9443/what-is-the-definition-of-primarily-opinion-based-on-su). Quote from answer by [Random](https://meta.superuser.com/users/307/random)

> deciding which facts to put forth as the advantage or disadvantage is based on personal preference and opinion.

Comment: Based on the answers it recieved I would have also choosen to close it also.

Comment: @Ramhound I've voted to close. I wonder whether that will remove the question from review audits?

Comment: "Opinion based" implies that there would be differences of opinion.  Some of the wording is typical of what would be associated with an opinion based question, but the question, itself, is easily supportable by facts that point to a single conclusion.  Of course, that's all irrelevant.  The reason it should not be closed is that it got 1,200 views. 12 upvotes, 2 favorites, and 2 highly upvoted answers, all within the last few weeks, so this isn't a stone age question from when the site had different standards.  Bot logic is that it must be good.  You wanna argue with a bot?

Comment: @fixer the bot is not always right, there is evidence of many bad review questions ... ;) And it has two close votes. Let's see what happens ...

Comment: @DavidPostill - This [review](http://superuser.com/review/late-answers/390820) made me laugh...talking about bad review audits.

Comment: @Ramhound Good one ... ;)